# How to make twitter api calls using access token

Tags: api, twitter

I have managed to get an access token from the twitter api. Now I want to use that token for my further data fetching things, so please help me here to get the details of my twitter account.

For example, lets say I wanted to get the user's data, [so when I tested this in apigee console](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json), I got my result.

But how to get the same result, using same api, by hitting on a browser using the access token
[something like this](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json/access_token=myToken)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex than the URL you suggested, but you can use Twitter's OAuth tool to generate the OAuth signature you need to make requests to its Home Timeline API call.

You can find the OAuth tool here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline#oauth-tool

Answer (score 0):

it's not like that when making twitter api calls you need to send consumer key, consumer secret, your_access_token and your_access_token_secret together
Eg: oauth_consumer_key="KEY",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="TIMESTAMP",oauth_nonce="NONCE",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="YOUR_TOKEN",oauth_signature="SIGN"
Source: https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-the-user-details-using-access-token/6325/3